# apt-get raises /usr/bin/test: Permission denied

Tags: apt, permissions

Since some time, whenever I call `sudo apt-get update` or use similar `apt-get` options, I get `/usr/bin/test: Permission denied`. An example:

```
username:~$ sudo apt-get update
Ign:2 http://...                 
<...>          
Hit:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/teejee2008/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease         
Fetched 86,0 kB in 2s (42,2 kB/s)
sh: 1: /usr/bin/test: Permission denied
sh: 1: /usr/bin/test: Permission denied
sh: 1: /usr/bin/test: Permission denied
Reading package lists... Done
```

`apt-get` still does its job and everything works fine. Still, the denied permissions do not seem to be regular behaviour and I would like to fix them.

Does anyone know how to solve or approach this problem?

Edit:

After deleting the file `/usr/bin/test` (which was an empty file), I get `/usr/bin/test: not found`

```
username:~$ sudo apt-get update 
Hit:1 http://...
<...>
Get:23 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe Translation-en [61,3 kB]
Fetched 362 kB in 2s (166 kB/s)                                                
sh: 1: /usr/bin/test: not found
sh: 1: /usr/bin/test: not found
sh: 1: /usr/bin/test: not found
Reading package lists... Done
```

It seems like some command is accessing the file. Does anyone have an idea how to debug this?

Comment: Related: [usr/bin/test not found after apt-get update](https://askubuntu.com/q/1075787/8005). There are no posted answers, but there is someting posited as a [solution in the comments](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1075787/usr-bin-test-not-found-after-apt-get-update#comment1766676_1075787).

Comment: There is also a possible solution [posted here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2397414&p=13787742#post13787742).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you deleted the file we cannot diagnose the problem now.

Please get the file that you deleted back by reinstalling the package that contains it:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall coreutils
```

If the original issue was caused by wrong permissions on `/usr/bin/test` this command will solve your problem as well.

Comment: Thanks again. For completeness: the original file `usr/bin/test` was an empty file.