# I accidentally deleted /usr/bin/test and now I can't update, upgrade and install packages

Tags: apt, package-management

I accidentally deleted `/usr/bin/test` and now I can't update, upgrade and install packages.

I already tried the solution here: [apt-get raises /usr/bin/test: Permission denied](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1100703/apt-get-raises-usr-bin-test-permission-denied), but this is the output I got:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  java-common libutempter0
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 29 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,353 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Ign:1 http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main amd64 coreutils amd64 8.32-4ubuntu2
Ign ...
Ign ...
Err:1 http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main amd64 coreutils amd64 8.32-4ubuntu2
  Could not connect to ph.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (202.79.184.254), connection timed out
E: Failed to fetch http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/coreutils/coreutils_8.32-4ubuntu2_amd64.deb  Could not connect to ph.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (202.79.184.254), connection timed out
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I also tried `sudo apt update --fix-missing` and got this output:

```
Err:8 http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish InRelease
  Could not connect to ph.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (202.79.184.254), connection timed out
Err:9 http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates InRelease
  Unable to connect to ph.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Err:10 http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-backports InRelease
  Unable to connect to ph.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Fetched 125 kB in 37s (3,339 B/s)
sh: 1: /usr/bin/test: not found
sh: 1: /usr/bin/test: not found
sh: 1: /usr/bin/test: not found
Reading package lists... Done
```

Please help me.

Comment: Any chance you can make a live CD? If so, you could create one with the exact same version and flavor of Ubuntu you have, boot to the live CD, mount your main filesystem somewhere, say, `/mnt/mainfs`, and then copy (not move, copy) the `/usr/bin/test` file from the live CD to the correct place in the main filesystem (in my example it would be this: `sudo cp /usr/bin/test /mnt/mainfs/usr/bin/test`). Simply taking the `/usr/bin/test` file from the live CD and putting it in the correct place on the main filesystem probobly would fix your issue.

Comment: hello thank you for responding but I am new in using Linux and I did not know what live CD is can you send me a  video reference to follow or anything about that. thank you

Comment: I'll send directions in a moment. What exact version of Ubuntu do you have? Normal Ubuntu? Kubuntu? 20.04? 21.10? You can probobly find this in the About section in Settings somewhere.

Comment: oh thank youu very much I had this version ```Ubuntu 21.10 x86_64``` I'll wait for your directions <3

Comment: `dpkg -S /usr/bin/test` shows that `/usr/bin/test` is provided by the package `coreutils`. You could try to reinstall and reconfigure it.

Comment: @starkus how can  I install and reconfigure it?

Comment: @paologonzales You're free to try whatever you want. But I'd advise against trying to reinstall/reconfigure it. If you want, the command to reinstall it is `sudo apt install --reinstall coreutils`. But I think you've already tried that, and given the `Could not connect` errors, I don't think that trying to reinstall it will work well. I suggest trying what I said instead.

Comment: that also what I think that is why I'm asking him what does he mean about installing and reconfiguring it. Im currently installing the ISO internet is slow

Comment: something with 'sudo dpkg -i /var/cache/apt/archives/coreutils*.deb'

Comment: Will `cp /usr/bin/[ /usr/bin/test` work for the  interm?

Comment: @doneal24 no /usr/bin/[ wants a closing ]

Comment: I'm somewhat surprised anything is trying to use `/usr/bin/test`, since `test`is a built-in in most common shells.

Comment: most solutions are going to involve downloading *something*; you are likely to need to figure out why you got `Could not connect to ph.archive.ubuntu.com`.  do you have an internet connection?

Comment: @chepner: "test" is not a built-in in sh. Most install scripts, for portability reasons, strive to use sh (as sh is the one shell always supposed to be present), and therefore also have to use the "posix" test program (also supposed to be present).

Comment: `sh` isn't really a shell (or at least,  the actual Bourne shell that originally bore the name is rarely used anymore); it's the umbrella name for whatever POSIX-compatible shell a POSIX-compliant system is required to provide.

Comment: And this is why you should be careful using su and sudo :-( I agree that the easiest is to copy the binary from another, healthy system (including a live cd).  You may want to experiment reinstalling Ubuntu on top if you do not care about the data on the system.

Comment: @ysth I think the error message may be misleading if the programmer did not expect that `test` might be missing.

Comment: You could always write a rudimentary replacement. Chances are that the install scripts only use a small subset of the /bin/test functionality, most likely checking for existing files.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen the "connection timed out" made me think it unlikely to be related to test missing

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I suggest getting the deleted file from a live USB and putting it back. Here's how.

1. Download the Ubuntu ISO for your version of Ubuntu. Given that you have Impish (your `apt` output indicates that), the Ubuntu 21.10 ISO should work for you. Download the ISO labeled Desktop Image [from here](https://releases.ubuntu.com/21.10/).
2. Download [balenaEtcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/). Get the x64 Linux version. Extract the zip. In a terminal, go into the extracted zip folder. Once you're there, if you do `ls`, you should see a file that ends in `.AppImage`. Do `chmod +x balenaEtcher-1.7.3-x64.AppImage`.
3. Run balenaEtcher with `./balenaEtcher-1.7.3-x64.AppImage`.
4. Find a flash drive that is bigger than 8GB in capacity, and put it in your computer. **All data on this flash drive will be destroyed.**
5. Select the downloaded ISO, and select the flash drive. Hit Flash.
6. Once it's done, reboot your computer, enter the boot menu, and select the flash drive. Press Try Ubuntu.
7. In the live USB session, mount the main system. It might automatically do it, and there might be a button in the GUI to do that. Figure out where it is mounted. I'll use `/mnt/mainfs` as an example, but you should use the real location.
8. Open a terminal, and run `sudo cp /usr/bin/test /mnt/mainfs/usr/bin/test`. Replace `/mnt/mainfs` with wherever you mounted your main system.
9. You're done. Shut down the live session, unplug the flash drive, and reboot. Normal Ubuntu will be back, and `apt` should work again.

Comment: This is a great answer, a bit more advanced users could just replace the use of balenaEtcher with a single dd cmd which is installed by default:
$ dd if=path/to/ubuntu.iso of=/dev/sdX bs=1m
Detailed answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/179146

Comment: Btw. if you still have a working Ubuntu there's even no need to use a Flash drive, you could just mount the .iso file. $ mount -o loop file.iso /mnt/dir

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/316407

Comment: @ValentinSolina I didn't know that, can you post an answer?

Comment: Here @cocomac https://askubuntu.com/a/1389039/1564755

Comment: If you are burning the ISO file into a USB then the correct term is Live "USB" not "CD".

Comment: @Someone Oops, I didn't know that. Feel free to [suggest an edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1388900/edit)

Comment: I have edited *(I am having more than 2k rep so my edits are applied immediately, feel free to rollback)* your answer and replaced Live CD with live session as that seems more appropriate. I have also changed the minimum capacity to 8GB as live session on a 4GB USB will break itself.

Comment: @Someone Just read through it, and your edit makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: #4 is still wrong Ubuntu 21.10 ISO is 2.9GB) and recommending a 3rd party software when Startup Disk Creator is installed by default makes no sense.

Answer (score 52):

You could use the `test` commandlet provided by `busybox` to temporarily replace a missing `/usr/bin/test` binary file.

First, check that you have busybox, and that its `test` works:

```
$ /usr/bin/busybox test -x /usr/bin/busybox && echo Works
Works
```

Then create a symbolic link:

```
$ sudo ln -s busybox /usr/bin/test
$ 
$ file /usr/bin/test
/usr/bin/test: symbolic link to busybox
```

Then re-install the `coreutils` package, which will overwrite the symlink with the proper binary implementation.

If you don't have `busybox`, you could even create `/usr/bin/test` as a shell script and leverage the shell's `test` builtin:

```
#!/bin/sh

test "$@"
```

(don't forget to make it executable, `chmod +x /usr/bin/test`) again re-installing `coreutils` right after.

Comment: Something to bear in mind is that Coreutils Test has some extensions which software might rely upon. If those happen to be absent from Busybox Test ([which does not seem to be properly documented](https://busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html)), it might break some scripts. As such, for a temporary solution using a `#!/bin/bash` script may be better.

Comment: The Debian "maintainer scripts" (i.e. the scripts run during package install) are supposed to run with a minimal POSIX compliant shell as `/bin/sh`. If they need extra features, the package needs to declare an explicit dependency, and this is uncommon.

Comment: `sudo ln -s busybox /usr/bin/test`. Wait. This creates a symlink pointing to `busybox`, right? But `busybox` can do so much more than just `busybox test`. So how is the system supposed to know that `busybox test` is supposed to be called?

Comment: Oh cool. "Busyboxes usually decide their "wanted functionality" by checking where they're called from. " https://android.stackexchange.com/a/64031/292651

Comment: Not "where they're called from", but "what name they're called under", as put in `argv[0]` by the caller. To demonstrate the difference, in bash, you can use `exec -a test busybox 1 = 1` to call the `busybox` binary with the name `test` in `argv[0]`, despite not _having_ any link to busybox under that name actually exist on the filesystem.

Answer (score 37):

The simplest solution I can think of, without using the package manager (since it does not work anymore):

1. Download the coreutils package:

   ```
   wget http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/coreutils/coreutils_8.32-4ubuntu2_amd64.deb
   ```

   *note: use browser if you don't have wget installed*.  Also note that the exact names are as of January 2022 - if you need to do this at a later date, file names will most likely have changed to reflect updated packages.
2. Unpack downloaded package

   ```
   dpkg-deb -R coreutils_8.32-4ubuntu2_amd64.deb coreutils_unpacked
   ```
3. Copy the missing test binary

   ```
   sudo cp coreutils_unpacked/usr/bin/test /usr/bin/test
   ```
4. Add executable permission

   ```
   sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/test
   ```

---

Or if you'd like to download the full .iso file

1. Download the iso file from the official site
2. Create a temp directory to mount iso file into

   ```
   mkdir ubuntu_iso_tmp
   ```
3. Mount iso file into newly created dir

   ```
   sudo mount -o loop ~/Downloads/Ubuntu_whatever.iso ubuntu_iso_tmp
   ```
4. Copy the missing test binary

   ```
   sudo cp ubuntu_iso_tmp/usr/bin/test /usr/bin/test
   ```

Comment: `cp -a` would be a good choice to preserve permissions, ownership, and mod-time from the package file.  (Then you wouldn't need `chmod`).  I almost always use `cp -a` for any copying I ever do; I forget which metadata *doesn't* get copied without `-a`, but clearly in this case you want to copy as much as possible, like you were extracting directly to there. Or just use `mv` since you don't need to unpacked version anymore.

Comment: I would use `apt-get download coreutils` instead of depending on wget a url that can disappear.

Comment: @ValentinSolina: You can roll back that edit (click on "edited N hours/days ago".  Braiam can always post another answer

Comment: Rolled back to `wget`-version, as `apt-get` is broken in this particular scenario.

Comment: In case package download link becomes invalid or you have a different Ubuntu version, search for coreutils on the official site: https://packages.ubuntu.com - that's how I found it

Answer (score 16):

For the specific case of `/usr/bin/test`, there's another program `/usr/bin/[` which is identical except that it requires an additional last argument which is `]`. GNU coreutils, which is the implementation of these programs under Ubuntu and other non-embedded Linux systems, ships those two programs as separate executables, so even if one is corrupted or missing, you can use the other. Create `/usr/bin/test` with the following content:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/\[ "$@" \]
```

Make it executable (`chmod a+rx /usr/bin/test`) and you have a completely valid replacement for `/usr/bin/test`.

Then run `apt reinstall coreutils` to get the normal `/usr/bin/test` back.

Comment: Why does one need to escape the brackets?

Comment: @Ruslan In this particular script, the brackets don't need to be escaped.

Answer (score 5):

You could reinstall the main package and let the triggers do the job. In this case `coreutils` and any provided tool of it will be reinstalled by the scripts of `coreutils`. Not only `test`.

1. Download the version installed on your system

   ```
   wget http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/coreutils/coreutils_8.32-4ubuntu2_amd64.deb
   ```
2. Unpack it to its destination

   ```
   sudo dpkg --unpack coreutils_8.32-4ubuntu2_amd64.deb
   ```
3. Configure or reconfigure it using its triggers:

   ```
   sudo dpkg --configure coreutils
   ```

Done.

Comment: I did mention at the beginning that this does not only restore `test`. Do you mean something else?

Comment: yes you did.  I don’t know why I misread it - perhaps scrolled to the beginning of another question. Comment deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Simply install the OS flavor locally on virtualbox and copy out and upload the binary to the system that’s missing it.